# I've tried everything but sql workbench does not even load

Tags: windows-7, installation, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've installed MySql workbench 6.3 CE for Windows 7 and I have Microsoft.Net framework 4.5 installed and VC redist (x64 and x86) 2015 installed. But every time I try to open the application nothing happens. I've checked windows task manager processes and observed that the Mysql process only opens for a brief moment and closes. I've tried reinstalling and restarting and also checked windows firewall for any problems that could block Mysql connections.

TlDr: workbench does not open, workbench process viewed only for a few moments, all prerequisites for the software installed.

Comment: Im sorry, Im basically a noob with this, how do i check event log?

Comment: I've googled how to use event viewer, I'll provide a log file in a bit.

Comment: [How to Open and Use Event Viewer in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/226084-event-viewer-open-use-windows-7-a.html)

Comment: Faulting application name: MySQLWorkbench.exe, version: 6.3.7.0, time stamp: 0x5758217b
Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524f83ff
Exception code: 0xc000001d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000092bc3
Faulting process id: 0x1a7c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1f16d1752e973
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120.dll
Report Id: 59db6470-5d60-11e6-bd1a-a08869460d33

Comment: there is also one for net framework related to mysql

Comment: Application: MySQLWorkbench.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Stack:
   at <Module>.wb.WBContextUI.init(wb.WBContextUI*, wb.WBFrontendCallbacks*, wb.WBOptions*)
   at <Module>.wb.WBContextUI.init(wb.WBContextUI*, wb.WBFrontendCallbacks*, wb.WBOptions*)
   at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])

Comment: For the next step I would --> uninstall the MySQL WB tool, reboot the machine, and then reinstall the tool, and try again. Report back your results.

Comment: As requested surprisingly I only got one error message in event viewer

Comment: Application: MySQLWorkbench.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Stack:
   at <Module>.wb.WBContextUI.init(wb.WBContextUI*, wb.WBFrontendCallbacks*, wb.WBOptions*)
   at <Module>.wb.WBContextUI.init(wb.WBContextUI*, wb.WBFrontendCallbacks*, wb.WBOptions*)
   at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])

Comment: Okay guys, i just got a previous version of Mysql wb working 6.1 to be exact. I'm guessing the 6.3 version of Mysql Wb bugged out on my system.